# How does one show that the Godel number of $L-$terms are computable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, computability

I was reading [these](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf) (page 100 paper pdf) notes and was trying to show the Godel number of $L-$terms are computable. The structural recursion they have for this:

[image]

I will use the symbol $g(t) = \ulcorner t \urcorner $ because writing the upper corner brackets in latex is really annoying.

and I wanted to put it in the recursive form that we've shown is computable (it's nearly the same as putting it in primitive recursion):

[image]

so I defined $G$ as follows:

$$
 G(a,n+1,c)=
\begin{cases}
 \langle SN(v_i) \rangle & (c)_0 = \langle SN(v_i) \rangle, v_i \in Variables \\
\langle SN(F), (c)_1, ... , (c)_n \rangle & o.w. \\
\end{cases}
$$

though I noticed that the last line just transalted to:

$$ \langle SN(F), (c)_1, ... , (c)_n \rangle = c $$

which looked extremely silly to me. Since it meant that $G(a,b,c)=c$. What did I do wrong? Is there something I missed?

I notice that this is more of a structural recursion than a normal recursion on natural numbers...so idk if that has to do with the issue.

---

**Context**: Definition of computable requested on comments:

Definition of computable is on page 82 paper:

[image]

though I had in mind using proposition 5.1.20 and 5.1.21:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a particular technical definition of "computable" you need to adhere to, or are you convinced enough of the Church-Turing thesis that you can just take it to mean, "anything I know how to write a program for"?

Comment: @ I did have a particular definition. I will add it.

Comment: Though, there are a bunch of theorem leading up to this statement that we are allowed to use (e.g. primitive recursion, which is what I was trying to use).

Comment: Note that you can define commands here. So `\newcommand{\godel}[1]{\ulcorner#1\urcorner}` should simplify writing $\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner$.

Comment: Are you sure that when you say "the Gödel numbers of L-terms are computable" what you mean is actually to take a term as input and produce its Gödel number as output? As you mention, that is pretty pointless. However, if you want to prove that the _set_ of Gödel numbers for L-terms is computable, what you need to do is take an _integer_ as an input and decide _whether or not_ that integer is the Gödel number of some L-term.

Comment: @AsafKaragila where do I put `\newcommand{\godel}[1]{\ulcorner#1\urcorner}` in my question?

Comment: Yes, right before the first time you would use it Is a good suggestion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you insert it so that I can see how its done? whenever I try to insert it appears in the question's text and I can't use the command... :/

Comment: @Pinocchio: It needs to be within math mode so the MathJax parser will see it, of course.

Comment: @HenningMakholm like place it at the top of the answer with money signs \$\$ \$\$ ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, Church-Turing thesis is fine. Though, now that I think about it feels too trivial to even explain in those terms, since we just recurse in the definition given above.